# How to get all posts assigned to a taxonomy term only?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I have a taxonomy called `projects` and it has 4 types of projects. Assume `new, current, past, future`.

In `taxonomy-projects.php` page I need to show selected `taxonomy term` posts only. Assume I selected `future` category. Then I need to show all posts under `future`.

Here what I have tried so far. But it is returning all the created taxonomies under `proejcts` taxonomy and all posts assigned to those created taxonomies.

```
$projects = get_terms('projects');

foreach($projects as $project) {
    wp_reset_query();
    $args = array('post_type' => 'project',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'projects',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $project->slug,
            ),
        ),
     );

     $loop = new WP_Query($args);
     if($loop->have_posts()) {

        echo '<h2>'.$project->name.'</h2>';

        while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
            echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a><br>';
        endwhile;

     }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to create your own query. The main query contains the current term's posts, you just need to run the default loop.

Comment: As @Milo said you don't need to create a new query. I think just checking the taxonomy term and putting each post under it's terms will solve the problem of yours. But one thing I am not sure that how you planned this ***"In `taxonomy-projects.php` page I need to show selected taxonomy term posts only. Assume I selected `future` category. Then I need to show all posts under `future`."*** ?

Comment: @the_dramatist yes exactly. What ever term selected, posts only assigned  to selected term should come. But with my code, all the terms and term related posts are coming.

Comment: Please share your `taxonomy-projects.php` source code, so we can modify the code get that functionality. @user2584538

Comment: @the_dramatist Your suggestion solved my problem. But how can I get taxonomy term in that way. ? I mean the title. In future term, Future as the title ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do it in many ways. You can introduce a form with a drop down input for the terms and pass it to a function through `POST` or `GET` method and the query the posts associated with the terms, then show them. Fro capturing the send data you can use [`admin_post_{$action}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_post_action/). Read thoroughly the documentation and do some search, you'll get necessary information to make this thing work.

You can use ***AJAX*** to make this thing more robust. For AJAXifing the system you can have a look at those below links-

1. https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins
2. https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)
3. https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)

From your question this is the only thing right now I can suggest.

Hope those helps.